# Is SMS MFA Status in Cognito user pools set by calling setPreferredMFA or is that something else?

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

when using **setPreferredMFA** the SMS MFA Status in Cognito user pools is disabled even if setPreferredMFA is set.

What does SMS MFA Status represent and what does it do when I enable it or disable it?

Thank you

Comment: When in doubt, never underestimate just how garbage AWS Cognito really is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing more but an inconsistency in AWS console/API responses. Example:
Let's enable SMS MFA for a user:

```sh
aws cognito-idp set-user-mfa-preference --sms-mfa-settings Enabled=true,PreferredMfa=true --access-token <value>
```

Yes, in console it still looks as if SMS MFA was not enabled. But this is not true. Let's get our user's data:

```sh
aws cognito-idp get-user --access-token <value>
```

```json
{
    "Username": "your-email@example.com",
    "UserAttributes": [
        {
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "491a3eba-381f-4c87-a7d6-befa21e49e82"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        },
        {
            "Name": "phone_number_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        },
        {
            "Name": "phone_number",
            "Value": "+1234567890"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "your-email@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "PreferredMfaSetting": "SMS_MFA",
    "UserMFASettingList": [
        "SMS_MFA"
    ]
}
```

What you want to look at is the `PreferredMfaSetting` attribute. It tells you what your user choose for himself/herself.

And if you now try to authenticate like this:

```sh
aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --client-id <value> --auth-parameters USERNAME=<value>,PASSWORD=<value>
```

You will receive a response like this:

```
{
    "ChallengeName": "SMS_MFA",
    "Session": "<session-value>",
    "ChallengeParameters": {
        "CODE_DELIVERY_DELIVERY_MEDIUM": "SMS",
        "CODE_DELIVERY_DESTINATION": "+*********7890",
        "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "your-email@example.com"
    }
}
```

Ok, so what is this thing in console doing? It is actually deprecated. Take a look at the documentation of the `MFAOptions` here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html

So let's just enable SMS MFA through the console and then check the output of `GetUser`:

```json
{
    "Username": "your-email@example.com",
    "UserAttributes": [
        {
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "491a3eba-381f-4c87-a7d6-befa21e49e82"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        },
        {
            "Name": "phone_number_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        },
        {
            "Name": "phone_number",
            "Value": "+1234567890"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "your-email@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "MFAOptions": [
        {
            "DeliveryMedium": "SMS",
            "AttributeName": "phone_number"
        }
    ],
    "PreferredMfaSetting": "SMS_MFA",
    "UserMFASettingList": [
        "SMS_MFA"
    ]
}
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: from where do you get tokens? I have a similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317364/how-to-programmatically-enable-or-disable-mfa-for-a-logged-user-in-aws-cognito-u

Comment: @msbomrel Relying on what you see in UI is not a good idea (at least in this case). Keep in mind that the UI is build on top of the existing API. It may have bugs (as in this case). Setting it all up with API always works.